# How to get first line of output from command line?

Tags: macos, shell, find

I'm running a find command that's returning multiple results, but I only need the first result. A bit of googling led me to the "read" command, but I couldn't figure it out, and the man page didn't prove too helpful.

Comment: Why not just pipe the results to a file? (i.e `$ mycommand > myfile.txt`)

Comment: @theMonster - that's not a pipe. That's redirecting the standard output to a file. A pipe would involve... a pipe. '|' e.g. `ls -l | head -1` - as answered by Jeff Clayton. Pipes are a pseudo file, though you can make them a file, using `mkfifo`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Enter your command (example: `ls -l`) then the `head` command with a pipe like so:

```
ls -l | head -1
```

note: there is documentation on this usage of 'head'

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/head.1.html

```
 -n number    The first number lines of each  input  file  is
              copied  to  standard output. The number option-
              argument must be a positive decimal integer.

 -number      The  number  argument  is  a  positive  decimal
              integer  with  the same effect as the -n number
              option.
```

Shown here and as mentioned in the comments, this also works depending on your unix-based distribution:

```
 ls -l | head -n 1
```

Comment: to get the top 10 lines you would change that to head -10

Comment: in your case it would be this...

Comment: find (command line arguments here) | head -1

Comment: `head -n 10` - ref `man head`

Comment: I am using OS X as he mentioned and head -1 works (head -10 as well) no extra args needed

Comment: Yes it works, but it is *not documented to work* - which means it will eventually break / stop working. ':-] - also try `head file1 fil2 file3 -n 1` with and without `-n`.

Comment: I used it 20 years ago in college, thinking it is not going to change any time soon (we used sun servers)

Comment: Yep, it has worked for long, I was using it in the mid 90's too, ;-)

Comment: to be completely correct, if you are going to use a script, you will want to use paths as well. on os x (i am using mavericks) it is /usr/bin/find (arguments) | /usr/bin/head -n 1   (-n added to make Hannu happy ;)

Comment: =) that is what $PATH is for ( LOL, I'm going to bed now! )

Comment: you cannot always rely on the environment in the path variable. major security flaw if you leave it out. hackers put their own command with same name in the path... also, if you run it as a cron job or other server command it will not have the local path that a user will.

Comment: many times i have seen (and even had happen to me) a cron job not working, because it relied on a path that was not set the same as the command line. that and being a sysadmin it was one of the first things instructed as the right way to do things.

Comment: Awesome, that does exactly what I needed. I didn't even know about the head command's existence. I also appreciate the banter between you two ;) Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can also get the last line by trading it with the tail command (use it exactly the same way)

Comment: Here is a fun one... say you wanted the second line only... you can use them in sequence. you would do it like this: find (stuff) | head -n 2 | tail -n 1   (clearly you could get a block of lines in order this way -- great for specific logging)

Comment: reversing those you could get the second to last line... or even say lines 2-7 of a file (play with it, it is cool stuff)

Comment: Very cool. That could definitely prove useful in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: More: `head -n -x` all but the x last lines, `tail -n +x` the remainder of the lines, starting at line x - more in the **ABS guide** referred to in my answer with info on `read`.

Answer (score 1):

I like lots of ways to tackle unix problems. Here's some others, assuming that `command` is replaced by whatever it is you're actually doing:

```
command | awk 'NR == 1 {print}'

command | sed -e 1q

TMP=`mktemp tempXXX`; command > ${TMP} ; ed ${TMP} << HERE
1p
HERE

command | split -1 - ; cat xaa ; rm -f x[a-z][a-z]

LINECOUNT=$(command | tee tempfile | wc -l | sed -e 's/ *//g'); \
  tail -$((${LINECOUNT} - 1)) tempfile | diff -u - tempfile | grep '^+' | \
  grep -v '^+++' | sed -e 's/^+//'
```

If your output is fixed length records (which may be true; example is for 80 characters of input plus a terminal newline):

```
command | dd ibs=81 count=1
```

At one point I worked on installing Unix systems from capacity constrained storage devices (floppy disks). We often had to find imaginative ways to use the limited set of commands that we could include on a 1.44MB floppy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the more command to control the amount of text that is shown at a time.

To solve your problem :

Redirect your output to a file you create.

Use For Loop with 1 cycle (counter = 1 , -1 each time). You need to use tokens for search function.

The For Loop will ECHO the first command.

Delete your File.

Store the echo of the FOR Loop in a variable (optional).

I can give some usage definitions if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

How to use `read`

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5"
1
2
3
4
5

$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | while read n; do  echo "n:$n" ; done
n:1
n:2
n:3
n:4
n:5

$
```

More info on how bash works is available at [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) in **`Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide`,**
there is one more guide on bash **`Bash Guide for Beginners`**.